# page doesn't display that text has been sent successfully when clicked on send button

Tags: php, html

so I'm trying to make the contact form using PHP with validations. So when the input fields are not filled and I click send button it displays the error that says to fill in all blanks but when I fill in everything and click on send button, it sends message to my email address but doesn't display that the message was sent successfully, it just says "page not found" here's my code for contact.php and send.php

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">

            <div class="col-12 heading">
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <?php 
                    $Msg = "";
                    if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
                        $Msg = "Please Fill in All Blannks";
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$Msg.'</div>';
                    }

                    if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
                        $Msg = "Your Message Has Been Sent";
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$Msg.'</div>';
                    }

                ?>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <form class="reportform" action="send.php" method="post">
                                    <input type="text" name="UName" placeholder="Full Name"><br>
                                    <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your e-mail"><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject"><br>
                                    <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
                                    <h6>By clicking send button, you agree our <a target="_blank" href="../credits/ppolicy.html">Privacy Policy</a></h6>
                                    <button type="submit" name="btn-send" class="btn btn-primary sendbtn">Send</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn-send'])){

   $UserName = $_POST['UName'];
   $Email = $_POST['Email'];
   $Subject = $_POST['Subject'];    
   $Msg = $_POST['msg'];

   if(empty($UserName) || empty($Email) || empty($Subject) || empty($Msg)) {

       header('location: contact.php?error'); 

   }

       else {
    $to = "nika.makhatadze17@gmail.com";

    if(mail($to,$Subject,$Msg,$Email)) {

        header("location: index.php?success");
    }
}
}

else {
    header("location: contact.php");
}
```

?>

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `Success` you redirect to `index.php?success` but you defined the Success case in your `contact.php`, so i would say you just have to change `header("location: index.php?success");` to `header("location: contact.php?success");`

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this code we mead some changes on your code

pass success msg value on header location

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-12 heading">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <?php 
                $Msg = "";
                if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
                    $Msg = "Please Fill in All Blannks";
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$Msg.'</div>';
                }

                if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
                    $Msg = "Your Message Has Been Sent";
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">'.$Msg.'</div>';
                }

            ?>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form class="reportform" action="send.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="UName" placeholder="Full Name"><br>
                <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your e-mail"><br>
                <input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject"><br>
                <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
                <h6>By clicking send button, you agree our <a target="_blank" href="../credits/ppolicy.html">Privacy Policy</a></h6>
                <button type="submit" name="btn-send" class="btn btn-primary sendbtn">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn-send'])){

   $UserName = $_POST['UName'];
   $Email = $_POST['Email'];
   $Subject = $_POST['Subject'];    
   $Msg = $_POST['msg'];

   $successMsg = 1;

   if(empty($UserName) || empty($Email) || empty($Subject) || empty($Msg)) {

       header('location: contact.php?error'); 

   }

       else {
    $to = "nika.makhatadze17@gmail.com";

    if(mail($to,$Subject,$Msg,$Email)) {

       header("location: index.php?success=".$successMsg);
    }
}
}

else {
    header("location: contact.php");
}
```

Comment: Feel free to ask anything about this

Comment: The problem was in redirecting to success popup. I fixed it. Thanks anyways <3